# Who was the Lord of Dragonstone?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Prior to Daenerys Targaryen announcing Gendry Baratheon as the Lord of Dragonstone, who was considered as the Lord of Dragonstone?

Based on the TV show, it was shown that Stannis Baratheon and his army were garrisoned at Dragonstone. After the death of Stannis (in the TV show), was there any indication with reference to who was Lord of Dragonstone?

Comment: In short: no one. In long: D&D just didn't think about it because it wasn't relevant but still no one was.